# Go: Interface method override from embedded structure

Tags: interface, go, overriding

Consider the following code:

```
type Intf interface {
    Method()
}

type TypeA struct {
    TypeBInst Intf
}

func (*TypeA) Method() {
    log.Println("TypeA's Method")
}

func (t *TypeA) Specific() {
    t.TypeBInst.Method() // Call override from TypeB
    log.Println("Specific method of TypeA")
}

type TypeB struct {
    *TypeA
}

func (*TypeB) Method() {
    log.Println("TypeB's Method")
}
```

Is there another way to call `func (*TypeB) Method()` from inside `func (t *TypeA) Specific()`  than storing a pointer to a `TypeB`'s instance inside the embedded `TypeA` instance of `TypeB`? Is it against golang principles?

Working example: [playground](http://play.golang.org/p/1rM0wEBluL)

Comment: Not sure if I understand the question at all: How on earth would could you possibly call a method without a receiver? If you do not have a TypeB at hand inside `func(*TypeA) Method()` you cannot call it's method. You try `func (*TypeA) Method(TypeB)` and pass in a TypeB, but thats for not what you try to do. What _does_ help: Stop thinking about inheritance, overriding and all that Java stuff.

Comment: One more: Have runnable playground code available, this helps providing answers.

Comment: @Volker you mean like [this](http://play.golang.org/p/tkfVUYnffb)? :D

Comment: @Volker Of course passing a pointer as a parameter is another solution, but I was wondering if it was against golang principles and if so what are the alternatives? I added a working example but it is not really the point of my question.

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve? This, to be honest, looks more like speculation about the type system than exploration of the possible-design-space for solving a specific problem.

Comment: @Vatine I'm not looking for a solution I just feel like it is not right. I've been working on a big project lately, and the global architecture is based on that usage of interfaces. I just want to know every possibilities to make it right. Maybe it's not the appropriate stackexchange network?

Comment: @thwd: Cute, but it's just a nil *TypeB in disguise. Or?

Answer (score 0):

> Is there another way to call func (*TypeB) Method() from inside func (t *TypeA) Specific() than storing a pointer to a TypeB's instance inside the embedded TypeA instance of TypeB?

Yes, [there is](http://play.golang.org/p/tkfVUYnffb):

```
package main

import "log"

type TypeB struct{}

func (*TypeB) Method() {
    log.Println("TypeB's Method")
}

func main() {
    (*TypeB).Method(nil)
}
```

But it only works for nilable receivers (without requiring an instance of the receiver).

> Is it against golang principles?

Not that I know of, but I personally have never required this in any project ever.

Comment: Type assertion or castsis what I'm trying to avoid here. `TypeA

Comment: There are no conversions and no assertions in that code.

Comment: Type assertion or casts is what I'm trying to avoid here. `TypeA`  need to call `TypeB` 's `Method()` to change the behavior of `TypeA`'s `Specific()` method to create `CustomTypes` based on `TypeA`

Comment: Sorry I missred your post! The problem with that solution is that I need to know the type of `TypeB`. I forgot to mention main constraint on this situation, `(*TypeA) Specific()` must be able to call `Method()` from any type that implements `Intf` interface.